# Is str.count() wrong?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, count

I'm having fun with some challenges and one of them makes me count substrings in a string. I have a problem specifically with "banana":

```
str = "banana"
print(str.count("ana"))
```

This should return 2 because "ana" appears two times:

```
b a n a n a
  a n a
      a n a
```

But str.count("ana") returns only 1. I've also tried with regexp:

```
import re
str = "banana"
print(len(re.findall("ana", str)))
```

But it also returns 1. Am I missing something?

thank you!

Comment: As the docs say, `str.count` counts _non-overlapping_ occurrences of the the substring.

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't call your variables `str` or any other built-in types/functions.

Comment: You can use regex module which supports overlapping pattern matching.

print(len(regex.findall("ana", str,overlapped=True)))

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are missing something.

[str.count(): Return the number of (non-overlapping) occurrences of substring sub in string s](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)